# Адаптивность сайта

Tags: position

Доброе время суток!
У меня следующая задача: по центру экрана должен быть круг, а за кругом 3 элемента (вкладки). Как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении экрана, вкладки сцеплялись с кругом?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black, red);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1px solid black;
}

.figure {
    position: relative;
}


.circle {
    width: 500px;
    height: 470px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 150px auto 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid black;

}

h1 {
    color: red;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.insert:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(247px, 85px);
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* top: 50%;
    left: 50%; */

}

.insert:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(18px, 211px) rotate(-60deg);
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.insert:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(481px, 202px) rotate(58deg);
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Visiting card site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="figure">
                <div class="insert">
                        <p>Биография</p>
                </div>
                <div class="insert">
                        <p>Навыки</p>
                </div>
                <div class="insert">
                        <p>Контакты</p>
                </div>
                <div class="circle">
                        <!-- <img src="" alt="#"> -->
                </div>
        </div>
        <h1 class="name">Поляков Семен</h1>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Должно быть как на скриншоте 1, а по факту - как на скриншоте 2
[image: Должно быть вот так.]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если решать задачу в рамках Вашей вёрстки, то можно блоку .figure задать фиксированную ширину (и выровнять по центру с помощью margin: 0 auto) - тогда внутреннее содержимое не будет разъезжаться.

Но Ваша вёрстка не адаптивна ни разу: на экранах меньше 767px появляется горизонтальный скролл. Или так и задумано?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black, red);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.1px solid black;
}

.figure {
    position: relative;
    width: 765px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.circle {
    width: 500px;
    height: 470px; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 150px auto 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid black;

}

h1 {
    color: red;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.insert:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(247px, 85px);
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* top: 50%;
    left: 50%; */

}

.insert:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(18px, 211px) rotate(-60deg);
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.insert:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    transform: translate(481px, 202px) rotate(58deg);
    background-color: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="figure">
    <div class="insert">
      <p>Биография</p>
    </div>
    <div class="insert">
      <p>Навыки</p>
    </div>
    <div class="insert">
      <p>Контакты</p>
    </div>
    <div class="circle">
      <!-- <img src="" alt="#"> -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="name">Поляков Семен</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Мне требуется сделать так, чтобы до разрешение 768px круг был по центру, а вкладки за кругом. Меньше 768px я сделаю вкладки просто в столбик.

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, ну, тогда по идее мой ответ должен Вам помочь

Comment: Если .figure прописать фиксированную ширину, тогда элементы в ней не двигаются при изменении разрешения. Они статично находятся на странице

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, так Вы ж хотите, чтоб они сцеплялись с кругом, а не разъезжались, правильно? Так они в этом случае и не должны двигаться.

Comment: Все верно. Я хочу, чтобы вкладки и круг сцепились. Но при фиксированной ширине круг и вкладки сцепленные, но не перемещаются к центру экрана.

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, в смысле - "не перемещаются к центру экрана"? Они изначально размещены по центру.

Comment: https://ibb.co/J56ZGSf вот скриншот. ширина .fiture поставил 766px

Comment: получается так, что блок .figure не "отлипает" от левого края

Comment: @СемёнПоляков, ну Вы мой-то пример внимательно посмотрели?? Естественно .figure надо выровнять по центру экрана с помощью margin: 0 auto; Вы бы хоть код мой запустили, что ли...

Comment: теперь все понял. Спасибо!